# Am i on right track with my java + Mysql database application for business software

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I have thoroughly researched my question and i think i have found some traces of solutions to my problem, but i am not quite sure if they are right and leading me to right track.So i need some expert advice and guidance here:

**My Problem:**
I am making a javaFx application with mysql as database, connection using JDBC. So my application will be used in offices where employees are connected with LAN and changes made by one employee in his system will be visible to others also and they can retrieve data from database.

So My problem is if  **A,B,C** are three employees and all of them have my software and mysql installed in their PC respectively and connected with LAN ,and if **A** creates an event/meeting with date and time, that event gets saved in his DB and then **B** and **C** will retrieve the data from DB when they open up my Software from their DB and see the updates.

Solution i have come up is, I install Software and MySQL on each **A,B,C**'s system + MySql with host as IP Address, and ask for username and password from users and good to go.

1. Am I going right  ??
2. If i install MySql DB on all user system then how can i link everyone's DB and maintain similar Data in each user DB.
3. How MySql uses IP Address as host instead of localhost to maintain same data in all user Databases. "DATA MUST ME SIMILAR".

My humble request to everyone who can share their knowledge and guide me on  this.

Comment: You are on the wrong track. In fact you are [Off the Tracks](http://www.reddirtreport.com/sites/default/files/articles/2016/02/images/Train-Wreck-1.jpg). Host your db in the cloud

Comment: Ever heard of Client-Server Architecture? There should be one central server (containing the Database and additional services, i.e. email server functionality) and one client application per user that connects to the database. I won't comment on things like replication now because you seem to be pretty new to the business and you should read about it when you got the basics.

Answer (score 1):

Install MySQL Server on a single computer and have everyone connected to it. Use transactions to make modifications atomic and you'll be good to go.

If you really want to have every client with a MySQL server, you'll have to use replication mechanisms, which is (usually) a pain to setup...

EDIT regarding your comment about not being able to install much software on client computers:

If you don't control how many clients are inter-connected, a central DB *is* what you need, especially if you want to make sure data are consistent between all clients. In that case, if the DB fails, you should show an error message until it is up again. That gives you a much simpler design, easier debugging and maintenance, but it creates a single-point-of-failure. Note that the central DB can be any chosen client computer, not necessarily a separate computer (but it's usually better to know that the DB computer is always running).

If having that single-point-of-failure is not an option for you, you should state it more clearly in your question and setup a cluster of DB with replication, which is cumbersome, or change your whole design to a fully distributed one and do the data [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) manually through network frameworks likes [jGroups](http://www.jgroups.org/). That will solve that single-point-of-failure but will come with a huge cost: (very much) harder maintenance, lots of debugging, lots of complaints from clients because they hit some hidden bug, etc.

Comment: Thanx @Matthieu for your answer. I read certain docs, tutoria based on your answer nd i think master to master replication would be nice solution but not feasiable to go and setup on every pc. Second i cannot install mysql on just one pc and make transaction from other pc, cause in that case if that pc gets shutdown or not active then db will not be available nd software will crash. Can' t i use same ip address and mysql db on all system isnt there any thing else i can use which is easy to setup for normal user.

Comment: @NiteshKhandelwal but if you want to have multiple clients you need to somehow synchronize them, and a central DB is perfect for that and makes the code cleaner. At some point you have to decidee under which conditions your system should stop working. Saying that it's when the central DB is down does makes sense.

Comment: @NiteshKhandelwal I edited my answer regarding your concerns.